# Append files to an existing argument list

Tags: vim

Given an existing argument list

```
file1.txt [file2.txt]
```

How can we append one or more files to that list so that it looks like this?

```
file1.txt [file2.txt] file3.txt file4.txt
```

What I have tried:

```
args {:args file3.txt file4.txt}
```

Comment: Answered here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/232350/235774

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [`:help :argadd`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3Aargadd) command. The `[count]` influences the position, the default is the current entry. So in your example, a simple

```
:argadd file3.txt file4.txt
```

will do. There's also an [`:help :argedit`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3Aargedit) variant that immediately switches to the added file (and several more commands around management of the argument list).